# Converting the output of a module from print to write mode

Tags: python, output

I have been trying to use a twobitreader package (http://pythonhosted.org//twobitreader/) to extract DNA sequence information, however I have ran into a problem. Whenever I use twobitreader.twobit_reader() module I am only able to obtain a printed output. What I would like to do is to write the output into a new file.

This is the information on this module from http://pythonhosted.org//twobitreader/:
twobit_reader takes a twobit_file (of class TwoBitFile) and an “input_stream” which can be any iterable (incl. file-like objects) writes output (FASTA format) using write (print if write=None) logs errors/warning to stderr

Likely, my limited knowledge with python programming is impeding me from accomplishing this task.

For example, here is some code that I wrote:

```
    def get_a(n):
      """get sequences from genome"""
      genome = twobitreader.TwoBitFile('hg19.2bit')
      bedfile = open(n+'.bed', 'r')
      o_f = open(n+'_FASTA.txt', 'w')
      twobitreader.twobit_reader(genome, bedfile)
      bedfile.close()
      o_f.close()
```

This ends up printing my sequences.

If I try to alter the twobitreader line to: `twobitreader.twobit_reader(genome, bedfile, o_f)` in the attempt to write the data to the file `o_f`, I get the error `'file' object is not callable`.

Comment: try: `twobitreader.twobit_reader(genome, bedfile, o_f.write)`

Comment: Ok I'll write an answer

Answer (score 0):

OP confirmed this worked:

```
twobitreader.twobit_reader(genome, bedfile, o_f.write)
```